# Restrict stack part width in Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I need to set a maximum size limit on a stack part width. Is this possible in Eclipse E4 to set a maximum size of the part? So in other words the use can resize the stack part but with a maximum size (so the part cannot be resized to use 50% of the screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no straightforward way to do this. Eclipse bug [361731](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361731) is tracking this and may be implemented in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7).

If you really want to do this it should be possible using a custom renderer for the Sash Renderer.

Comment: Seems this one is still not implemented in Oxygen.